# rsync remote to local only files older than certain time

Tags: linux, rsync, remote, date-modified

I want to rsync from a remote to local files that are older (or newer) than a certain time.

I've seen answers that say `find /src/path -mtime -1 | rsync ...` but that only work if the dir is seen locally.  Since it's remote it's not visible.

So how can I run the `find` on remote and rsync its results back to local?

Answer (score 0):

rsync has a `--list-only` option, which provides an index of the remote files, including timestamps:

```
$ rsync --list-only $REMOTE
drwx------            160 2018/09/04 12:55:12 .
-rw-r--r--          1,348 2018/09/04 12:52:33 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--             55 2018/09/04 12:52:33 .bashrc
...
```

Filtering on this list to select only appropriate dates, and then feeding that into a subsequent rsync's `--files-from` argument (which can refer to stdin, by using `--files-from=-`) should do the job.

For example, the following will rsync files with an mtime between 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-07 to the local machine (with appropriate values of `$REMOTE` and `$LOCAL_PATH`; note `$5` in the awk command refers to the fifth column - i.e. the filename - from the rsync output)

```
$ rsync --list-only $REMOTE | awk '/2018-08-0[1-7]/ {print $5}' | rsync --files-from=- $REMOTE $LOCAL_PATH
```

This doesn't answer the full problem of using `find`'s `-mtime`-type specifiers, but further parsing of the date string (e.g. using `date`) could be done to extend this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` as the remote path argument in rsync:

```
rsync -av $REMOTE:'`find /src/path -type f -mtime -1 -print`' $LOCAL_PATH
```